# Firefox inspector blinks yellow on one line + W3C Validation

Tags: html, firefox, wordpress-theming

I am building blog on wordpress an I tried to validate my site with w3c validator.

It returned me this:

> Line 22, Column 474: Bad value http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two|Source+Sans+Pro|PT+Serif|PT+Sans+Narrow for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point. 
>   …rrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>#masthead .site-…
>   Syntax of IRI reference:

So I tried to find this issue. I have runned Firefox Inspector and this line (arrowed) started to blink. What does it mean? Is there my issue what was found by Validator?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`|` characters should be encoded as `%7C` in URLs.

Comment: As per the URL standard http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt yes, but it’s odd that “|” must be encoded. It works well, and Google uses it in the markup it generates for an author who wants to use two or more Google fonts.

Comment: @sdybowski — Press Shift+5, 7, Shift+c. Or find a URL encoding function in your programming language of choice. Or use the find and replace function of your editor.